# Combinations the sum of digits [SOLVED]

Tags: combinatorics

Got quick question that bothers me but looks simple. What i try to look for is the amount of combinations of (x) going beyond (x) where sum of digits is still x. For instance lets start with 4.

4 
13 
22
31
40
103
112
121
130
...
3001
3010
3100
4000

All possible combinations are 35( from 4 up to 4000)..however is there a formula to calculate that? In addition is there a formula that can go beyond 4 digits but still summing to 4. Next sequence would be like this:

(5 digits)
10003 
10012 
10021
10030
10102
........
i would like to plug in any number of digits and to know the sum so with 5 digis it would be everything we had with 4 which was 35 plus whatever combinations does 5 digits has combined. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2):

For $k$ digits, the problem can be solved by finding solutions to
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_k=n$$

But $x_1\gt0$, as otherwise the number of digits would change. Let $X=x_1-1$. Then, $X\ge0$. All other $x_i\ge0$, where $i\gt1$.

$$X+1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_k=n$$

Thus, we need to find the number of non negative integral solutions to
$$X+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_k=n-1$$

This can be solved using the [Stars and Bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

The answer thus is
$$\binom{n+k-2}{n-1}$$

Comment: Thank you for the comment, however i'm novice in mathematics so i'm not really grasping the notation nor the answer. Is it possible for you to make an example with numbers? Thank You.

Comment: @user356448 Do you know what $\binom{n}{r}$ means?

Comment: is it the factorials?

Comment: @user356448 $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$, and it can denote the number of ways of choosing $r$ objects from a collection of $n$ distinct objects. I don't know how to explain without this. You could read up about Stars and Bars as your problem is a direct application of that.

Comment: @user356448 But I hope that the translation of the problem into finding the number of solutions to the given equation is clear.